# Required no PHP

Tags: php, redis

Sou iniciante no PHP e estou tentando importar um plugin para minha pagina, porem não sei como chama-lo, atualmente estou usando o `phpspreadsheet` e importo ele desta forma:

```
  require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/creating/assets/plugins/phpspreadsheet/vendor/autoload.php";
```

Agora estou tentando usar o Redis, para um sistema de cache, porem não sei qual arquivo da pasta dele chamar, não tem um `autoload.php` como o `phpspreadsheet` a estrutura da pasta é a seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando algo do tipo:

```
 require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/creating/assets/plugins/cache-master/Simple/";
```

Comment: Poderia compartilhar o caminho onde encontra-se o arquivo onde você tenta fazer o require e o caminho absoluto da onde encontra-se a pasta creating? Caso seja no mesmo nível basta usar o `__DIR__`

Comment: Caminho do Require : C:\xampp\htdocs\creating\assets\plugins




Caminho creating : C:\xampp\htdocs\creating